# Error after adding a new post while serving blogdown site

Tags: r, r-markdown, hugo, blogdown

I recently built a website using `blogdown` package in r. I added two posts and served site, everything was working fine.

After adding third post when I tried to run `blogdown:::serve_site()`, started getting error:

> Building sites … ERROR 2019/02/14 18:32:39 in .Render: Failed to execute template "_default/summary.html": "/Users/abc/fff/themes/hugo-tranquilpeak-theme/layouts/_default/summary.html:5:23": execute of template failed: template: _default/summary.html:40:9: executing "_default/summary.html" at : error calling partial: "/Users/abc/fff/themes/hugo-tranquilpeak-theme/layouts/partials/post/meta.html:5:23": execute of template failed: template: partials/post/meta.html:8:7: executing "partials/post/meta.html" at : error calling partial: "/Users/abc/fff/themes/hugo-tranquilpeak-theme/layouts/partials/post/category.html:5:23": execute of template failed: template: partials/post/category.html:5:23: executing "partials/post/category.html" at <.>: range can't iterate over Data Visualization
>   ERROR 2019/02/14 18:32:39 render of "taxonomyTerm" failed: "/Users/abc/fff/themes/hugo-tranquilpeak-theme/layouts/taxonomy/category.terms.html:6:25": execute of template failed: template: taxonomy/category.terms.html:6:25: executing "taxonomy/category.terms.html" at : error calling apply: can't apply over Data Visualization
>   Total in 81 ms
>
> Error: Error building site: failed to render pages: render of "page" failed: "/Users/abc/fff/themes/hugo-tranquilpeak-theme/layouts/_default/single.html:31:19": execute of template failed: template: _default/single.html:1:3: executing "_default/single.html" at : error calling partial: "/Users/abc/fff/themes/hugo-tranquilpeak-theme/layouts/partials/head.html:31:19": execute of template failed: template: partials/head.html:28:7: executing "partials/head.html" at : error calling partial: "/Users/abc/fff/themes/hugo-tranquilpeak-theme/layouts/partials/meta.html:31:19": execute of template failed: template: partials/meta.html:31:19: executing "partials/meta.html" at <.>: range can't iterate over Data Visualization
>
> To stop the server, run servr::daemon_stop("4471654616") or restart your R session
>   Serving the directory /Users/abc/fff at http://127.0.0.1:4321

Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

I am having a similar issue.  Would be nice to get this resolved.  Any suggestions would be nice.

```
Building sites â€¦ ERROR 2019/12/27 15:08:27 render of "taxonomy" failed: "C:\Users\xxxxx\OneDrive\Documents\blog\xxxxx\themes\hugo-tranquilpeak-theme\layouts\taxonomy\category.html:5:23": execute of template failed: template: taxonomy/category.html:17:17: executing "taxonomy/category.html" at <.Render>: error calling Render: "C:\Users\xxxxx\OneDrive\Documents\blog\xxxxx\content\post\2019-11-11-r-s-demise-higly-overblown.html:5:23": failed to execute template "_default/summary.html" v: "C:\Users\xxxxx\OneDrive\Documents\blog\xxxxx\themes\hugo-tranquilpeak-theme\layouts\_default\summary.html:5:23": execute of template failed: template: _default/summary.html:40:9: executing "_default/summary.html" at <partial "post/meta" .>: error calling partial: "C:\Users\xxxxx\OneDrive\Documents\blog\xxxxx\themes\hugo-tranquilpeak-theme\layouts\partials\post\meta.html:5:23": execute of template failed: template: partials/post/meta.html:8:7: executing "partials/post/meta.html" at <partial "post/category.html" .>: error calling partial: "C:\Users\xxxxx\OneDrive\Documents\blog\xxxxx\themes\hugo-tranquilpeak-theme\layouts\partials\post\category.html:5:23": execute of template failed: template: partials/post/category.html:5:23: executing "partials/post/category.html" at <.>: range can't iterate over R
ERROR 2019/12/27 15:08:27 render of "section" failed: "C:\Users\xxxxx\OneDrive\Documents\blog\xxxxx\themes\hugo-tranquilpeak-theme\layouts\_default\list.html:5:23": execute of template failed: template: _default/list.html:15:15: executing "_default/list.html" at <.Render>: error calling Render: "C:\Users\xxxxx\OneDrive\Documents\blog\xxxxx\content\post\2019-11-11-r-s-demise-higly-overblown.html:5:23": failed to execute template "_default/summary.html" v: "C:\Users\xxxxx\OneDrive\Documents\blog\xxxxx\themes\hugo-tranquilpeak-theme\layouts\_default\summary.html:5:23": execute of template failed: template: _default/summary.html:40:9: executing "_default/summary.html" at <partial "post/meta" .>: error calling partial: "C:\Users\xxxxx\OneDrive\Documents\blog\xxxxx\themes\hugo-tranquilpeak-theme\layouts\partials\post\meta.html:5:23": execute of template failed: template: partials/post/meta.html:8:7: executing "partials/post/meta.html" at <partial "post/category.html" .>: error calling partial: "C:\Users\xxxxx\OneDrive\Documents\blog\xxxxx\themes\hugo-tranquilpeak-theme\layouts\partials\post\category.html:5:23": execute of template failed: template: partials/post/category.html:5:23: executing "partials/post/category.html" at <.>: range can't iterate over R
ERROR 2019/12/27 15:08:27 render of "home" failed: "C:\Users\xxxxx\OneDrive\Documents\blog\xxxxx\themes\hugo-tranquilpeak-theme\layouts\index.html:5:23": execute of template failed: template: index.html:14:15: executing "index.html" at <.Render>: error calling Render: "C:\Users\xxxxx\OneDrive\Documents\blog\xxxxx\content\post\2019-11-11-r-s-demise-higly-overblown.html:5:23": failed to execute template "_default/summary.html" v: "C:\Users\xxxxx\OneDrive\Documents\blog\xxxxx\themes\hugo-tranquilpeak-theme\layouts\_default\summary.html:5:23": execute of template failed: template: _default/summary.html:40:9: executing "_default/summary.html" at <partial "post/meta" .>: error calling partial: "C:\Users\xxxxx\OneDrive\Documents\blog\xxxxx\themes\hugo-tranquilpeak-theme\layouts\partials\post\meta.html:5:23": execute of template failed: template: partials/post/meta.html:8:7: executing "partials/post/meta.html" at <partial "post/category.html" .>: error calling partial: "C:\Users\xxxxx\OneDrive\Documents\blog\xxxxx\themes\hugo-tranquilpeak-theme\layouts\partials\post\category.html:5:23": execute of template failed: template: partials/post/category.html:5:23: executing "partials/post/category.html" at <.>: range can't iterate over R
ERROR 2019/12/27 15:08:27 render of "page" failed: "C:\Users\xxxxx\OneDrive\Documents\blog\xxxxx\themes\hugo-tranquilpeak-theme\layouts\_default\single.html:31:19": execute of template failed: template: _default/single.html:1:3: executing "_default/single.html" at <partial "head.html" .>: error calling partial: "C:\Users\xxxxx\OneDrive\Documents\blog\xxxxx\themes\hugo-tranquilpeak-theme\layouts\partials\head.html:31:19": execute of template failed: template: partials/head.html:28:7: executing "partials/head.html" at <partial "meta.html" .>: error calling partial: "C:\Users\xxxxx\OneDrive\Documents\blog\xxxxx\themes\hugo-tranquilpeak-theme\layouts\partials\meta.html:31:19": execute of template failed: template: partials/meta.html:31:19: executing "partials/meta.html" at <.>: range can't iterate over R
Total in 2145 ms
Error: Error building site: failed to render pages: render of "taxonomyTerm" failed: "C:\Users\xxxxx\OneDrive\Documents\blog\xxxxx\themes\hugo-tranquilpeak-theme\layouts\taxonomy\category.terms.html:6:25": execute of template failed: template: taxonomy/category.terms.html:6:25: executing "taxonomy/category.terms.html" at <apply .Params.categories "urlize" ".">: error calling apply: can't apply over R
Building sites â€¦ ERROR 2019/12/27 15:08:30 render of "taxonomy" failed: "C:\Users\xxxxx\OneDrive\Documents\blog\xxxxx\themes\hugo-tranquilpeak-theme\layouts\taxonomy\tag.html:5:23": execute of template failed: template: taxonomy/tag.html:17:17: executing "taxonomy/tag.html" at <.Render>: error calling Render: "C:\Users\xxxxx\OneDrive\Documents\blog\xxxxx\content\post\2019-11-11-r-s-demise-higly-overblown.html:5:23": failed to execute template "_default/summary.html" v: "C:\Users\xxxxx\OneDrive\Documents\blog\xxxxx\themes\hugo-tranquilpeak-theme\layouts\_default\summary.html:5:23": execute of template failed: template: _default/summary.html:40:9: executing "_default/summary.html" at <partial "post/meta" .>: error calling partial: "C:\Users\xxxxx\OneDrive\Documents\blog\xxxxx\themes\hugo-tranquilpeak-theme\layouts\partials\post\meta.html:5:23": execute of template failed: template: partials/post/meta.html:8:7: executing "partials/post/meta.html" at <partial "post/category.html" .>: error calling partial: "C:\Users\xxxxx\OneDrive\Documents\blog\xxxxx\themes\hugo-tranquilpeak-theme\layouts\partials\post\category.html:5:23": execute of template failed: template: partials/post/category.html:5:23: executing "partials/post/category.html" at <.>: range can't iterate over R
ERROR 2019/12/27 15:08:30 render of "section" failed: "C:\Users\xxxxx\OneDrive\Documents\blog\xxxxx\themes\hugo-tranquilpeak-theme\layouts\_default\list.html:5:23": execute of template failed: template: _default/list.html:15:15: executing "_default/list.html" at <.Render>: error calling Render: "C:\Users\xxxxx\OneDrive\Documents\blog\xxxxx\content\post\2019-11-11-r-s-demise-higly-overblown.html:5:23": failed to execute template "_default/summary.html" v: "C:\Users\xxxxx\OneDrive\Documents\blog\xxxxx\themes\hugo-tranquilpeak-theme\layouts\_default\summary.html:5:23": execute of template failed: template: _default/summary.html:40:9: executing "_default/summary.html" at <partial "post/meta" .>: error calling partial: "C:\Users\xxxxx\OneDrive\Documents\blog\xxxxx\themes\hugo-tranquilpeak-theme\layouts\partials\post\meta.html:5:23": execute of template failed: template: partials/post/meta.html:8:7: executing "partials/post/meta.html" at <partial "post/category.html" .>: error calling partial: "C:\Users\xxxxx\OneDrive\Documents\blog\xxxxx\themes\hugo-tranquilpeak-theme\layouts\partials\post\category.html:5:23": execute of template failed: template: partials/post/category.html:5:23: executing "partials/post/category.html" at <.>: range can't iterate over R
ERROR 2019/12/27 15:08:30 render of "taxonomy" failed: "C:\Users\xxxxx\OneDrive\Documents\blog\xxxxx\themes\hugo-tranquilpeak-theme\layouts\taxonomy\category.html:5:23": execute of template failed: template: taxonomy/category.html:17:17: executing "taxonomy/category.html" at <.Render>: error calling Render: "C:\Users\xxxxx\OneDrive\Documents\blog\xxxxx\content\post\2019-11-11-r-s-demise-higly-overblown.html:5:23": failed to execute template "_default/summary.html" v: "C:\Users\xxxxx\OneDrive\Documents\blog\xxxxx\themes\hugo-tranquilpeak-theme\layouts\_default\summary.html:5:23": execute of template failed: template: _default/summary.html:40:9: executing "_default/summary.html" at <partial "post/meta" .>: error calling partial: "C:\Users\xxxxx\OneDrive\Documents\blog\xxxxx\themes\hugo-tranquilpeak-theme\layouts\partials\post\meta.html:5:23": execute of template failed: template: partials/post/meta.html:8:7: executing "partials/post/meta.html" at <partial "post/category.html" .>: error calling partial: "C:\Users\xxxxx\OneDrive\Documents\blog\xxxxx\themes\hugo-tranquilpeak-theme\layouts\partials\post\category.html:5:23": execute of template failed: template: partials/post/category.html:5:23: executing "partials/post/category.html" at <.>: range can't iterate over R
ERROR 2019/12/27 15:08:30 render of "home" failed: "C:\Users\xxxxx\OneDrive\Documents\blog\xxxxx\themes\hugo-tranquilpeak-theme\layouts\index.html:5:23": execute of template failed: template: index.html:14:15: executing "index.html" at <.Render>: error calling Render: "C:\Users\xxxxx\OneDrive\Documents\blog\xxxxx\content\post\2019-11-11-r-s-demise-higly-overblown.html:5:23": failed to execute template "_default/summary.html" v: "C:\Users\xxxxx\OneDrive\Documents\blog\xxxxx\themes\hugo-tranquilpeak-theme\layouts\_default\summary.html:5:23": execute of template failed: template: _default/summary.html:40:9: executing "_default/summary.html" at <partial "post/meta" .>: error calling partial: ## Heading ##"C:\Users\xxxxx\OneDrive\Documents\blog\xxxxx\themes\hugo-tranquilpeak-theme\layouts\partials\post\meta.html:5:23": execute of template failed: template: partials/post/meta.html:8:7: executing "partials/post/meta.html" at <partial "post/category.html" .>: error calling partial: "C:\Users\xxxxx\OneDrive\Documents\blog\xxxxx\themes\hugo-tranquilpeak-theme\layouts\partials\post\category.html:5:23": execute of template failed: template: partials/post/category.html:5:23: executing "partials/post/category.html" at <.>: range can't iterate over R
  Total in 1930 ms
Error: Error building site: failed to render pages: render of "taxonomyTerm" failed: "C:\Users\xxxx\OneDrive\Documents\blog\xxx\themes\hugo-tranquilpeak-theme\layouts\taxonomy\category.terms.html:6:25": execute of template failed: template: taxonomy/category.terms.html:6:25: executing "taxonomy/category.terms.html" at <apply .Params.categories "urlize" ".">: error calling apply: can't apply over R
'hugo" -d "public' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error in shell(cmd, mustWork = TRUE, intern = intern) : 
  '"hugo" -d "public" --themesDir themes -t hugo-tranquilpeak-theme' execution failed with error code 1
```